# NodeJS socket IO stop emitting randomly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm running Node 0.6.16 and all the modules are up to date at least according to npm (win7 x64). I could notice that, even if I have no disconnection occurring, but for some reason, after a while, I couldn't tell, maybe 1 hour, the browser doesn't receive any data. It appears to be more frequent on FF than on Chrome.

```
socket.on('disconnect', function (){console.log('disconnected')});
```

This never fires for that particular event (I mean it could happen but then I get the log and socket.io auto reconnects - In this case, nothing happens, it just stops working and this is the most frequent event).

So I don't know where to look. NodeJS still logs an heartbeat but for some reason, the connection is not going through. I am suspecting that, on tab change of (any?) browser, after a while, as the window / tab doesn't have focus anymore, socket.io stops receiving data ? I could be wrong and it could be not related to the focus, but this is my primary lead. Anyone else got any ideas?

**Edit**: client side is pretty straight forward :

```
socket = io.connect('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8081', {secure:false, 'reconnect': true, 'reconnection delay': 500, 'max reconnection attempts': 10});      
            socket.on('connect', function(){console.log('connected')});
            socket.on('message', function(data){//do something);        

            socket.on('disconnect', function (){console.log('disconnected')});
```

**Edit2** : After updating to latest version of socket.io (1.2.1) and node v0.10.35 I still have the same issue. Even more surprising, I added the following piece of code in the client:

```
function checkSocket(){
    if(socket){
        if(!socket.connected){
            console.log('socket disconnected');
            clearInterval(intv);
        }
    }       
}

intv = setInterval(checkSocket, 1000);
```

While the function runs every second, it never logs that the socket is disconnected, even if it does not receive anything anymore and still being sent heartbeats..

**Edit3:** Ok it was on my server side code, some socket were being destroyed. Also updated to v1.x and forced reconnection.

Comment: currently im doing the same set (node.js and socket.io), it works perfectly for me on all browsers, may be you could show us some of your client side code

Comment: I think this must resolved by now.

Comment: I'm also having this problem. My project is a radio that needs the sockets to get the currently playing song/cover. Long polling worked before but failed for a large amount of requests.

I ended up binding to window blur and focus with a setTimeout that emits a request to rejoin the room (which then resends the relevant data).

Hoping to find a better solution one day!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I still haven't figured it out...

Comment: Could you make a full example that we can experiment with?  I suspect that this isn't really a problem and is as-documented.  Socket.IO doesn't really get disconnected unless something catastrophic happens.  Many transitory connection issues are hidden and swallowed by Socket.IO itself.  Also, what transport(s) are you using?  Finally, if you could record a packet capture, that would be very helpful.

Comment: I'm testing again with a basic emitting ever X seconds app. So far it seems the issue is on more on the Chrome side than FF but will go to end of my tests to update the post... but so far it breaks after 20 minutes.

Comment: Will still monitor but it seems fixed. bad server code.

Comment: Try sending large messages to test out if its a buffer flushing issue.

Comment: Not relevant to the question but I used to use a timer to check the socket conn, now I use this: socket.on('disconnect', function() { console.log("disconnected!"); socket.io.close(); }); You can also check for errors with: socket.on('connect_error', function() { console.log("error!"); socket.io.close(); }); if there's a server issue, otherwise the client socket keeps logging error messages every 3 seconds.

Comment: How about adding your "server-side" working code for future users ?

Comment: Are you getting a zero length chunk in the "data" event?  This would mean the socket is closed.

Comment: Why are you running this on such an old version of Node.js? Current version is 0.12. It may have no effect, but it couldn't to try upgrading, couldn't it?

Comment: I see you fixed it, you should really write a nice answer and answer your own question for someone in the future.

Comment: I'm preparing a full answer about it, just testing a last few things to make sure everything is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since it seems I have no more issue, I thought I would share my back-end code. My issue I believe was that I was overwriting the socket.

```
var clients = {};
var app = require('https').createServer(options),
io = require('socket.io').listen(app);  
app.listen(8081);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(__socket) {
    var id = __socket.id;
    var ip = __socket.request.connection.remoteAddress;
    clients[id] = {socket:__socket, ip:ip}; 
    clients[id].socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        delete clients[id];     
   });
});
```